# Unequal Sample Size

Tags: t-test, sample-size

i have unequal sample sizes for my experimental and control group. can i just simply pair the samples from both groups with similarities (example, similar pre-test scores and gender) so that I can have equal samples from both groups?

Comment: That is inappropriate and unnecessary.  See the answer that is given..

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason you wanted same sample size?

It is statistically more sound to just use a pooled sample variance to estimate the standard deviation, and then use a standard t-test. This assumes the samples are normally distributed.

Depending on whether you have the same variance or not, you might want to consider [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_unequal_sample_sizes,_equal_variance) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_unequal_sample_sizes,_unequal_variances).

Just referencing the link above, if you assume equal variance you will have the pooled sample standard deviation given by:

$$s_p = \sqrt{\frac{(n_1-1)s_{X_1}^2+(n_2-1)s_{X_2}^2}{n_1+n_2-2}}$$

Now you can perform the t-test using this t statistic, that under the null will have $n - 2$ degrees of freedom:

$$t = \frac{\bar {X}_1 - \bar{X}_2}{s_p \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}}$$

Comment: You need to define n as n$_1$ + n$_2$..

Comment: In the unequal variance case the test statistic is different and has Welch's distribution which is approximated by a t distribution with an approximate number of degrees of freedom that can be a non-integer.